# Passing Parent Element to Method from MarkupBuilder

Tags: grails, groovy, taglib, markupbuilder

I have a custom taglib in Grails and I am using MarkupBuilder to help drive some dynamic forms.  I need to pull some of this form creation code out into their own classes/methods so they can be reused and I'd like to be able to use MarkupBuilder inside these other classes/methods.  So I have something like...

```
def formContainer = new MarkupBuilder(out)
formContainer.form(...) {
  table() {
     tr() {
       td() {
          // here I want to call a method and pass a reference to td()
          generateSomeFormData(this) // but this doesn't work.
       }
     }
   }
}
```

In the td(), I want to call a method but I need to pass it a reference to td.  'this' doesn't seem to reference that element.

My other method might look something like (very generic to get the point across)

```
generateSomeFormData(parentElement) {
   parentElement.input(type:'text')
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe

```
      generateSomeFormData( delegate )
```

should work